# WAMP - for some reason .php gets added to URL/$_GET-value?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay, I reinstalled WAMP, latest version, on a Windows 10 computer - it had been working fine, it was just that I tried to get mod_xsendfile to work with a project of mine, and I wanted to upgrade just to see if it made any difference.

However, I'm experiencing a weird problem after reinstall. For some reason, it seems to not really use the .htaccess (it does, however it seems there is something weird - if I comment out the .htaccess content, it stops processing CSS and such, so it works).

Here's the specific problem - I'm using .htaccess to make "pretty urls" - so I can write `domain.com/gallery` instead of `domain.com/index.php?page=gallery` (the latter works). If I write the first one, nothing shows up on the page, which is expected, since if I echo out the `$_GET['page']` variable, I get `gallery.php` returned - instead of just `gallery`. If I echo out the same after doing `index.php?page=gallery` it echos out `gallery` as it should. I just don't get where it gets the `.php` bit. It doesn't get assigned in code, it's just here it happens (the site is developed on a Mac using MAMP, and the codes work without problem there, more or less same versions: Apache 2.4.x and PHP 7.x).

So, here's my .htaccess (although I'm thinking perhaps it's something else):

```
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (script|style|users|webgfx|translations|setup|conf)/(.+)$ $1/$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(update_cookie.php|showfile.php|current_uploads.php|deletefile.php|language.php|gallery.php|quotes.php|retrieve_folder.php|check_email.php|config.php|delete_setup.php|functions.php|get_settings.php|get_update_info.php|get_userinfo.php|license.txt|login.php|process_search.php|process_setup.php|returnmessages.php|send_email.php|statistics_processing.php|update_settings.php|upload.php|process_upload.php|create_public_link.php)$ $1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(coreclass.php|coreclass|functions.php|functions|language.php|language)$ index

RewriteRule ^index.php?page=index|^index index.php [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 5 years"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Is there a setting anywhere in Apache or something that would automatically append `.php` or `.html` for such "nice urls"? **Note: I do have a gallery.php-file in the folder, but it should only be loaded via `index.php?page=gallery`**

If there's anything else I need to provide, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit - allow +MultiViews was turned on by default, for some obscure reason. Why in the world someone would have this on by default is beyond me, but that was it. Everything works as it should now.

I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/337626/how-is-apache-mapping-files-without-extensions

Answer (score -1):

You have to exclude the destination you are rewriting to :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php|.*\.).*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: No, you actually don't have to do that